# Install newer version of mongodb for travis-ci

Tags: node.js, mongodb, travis-ci

When running tests on travis the current default version is 2.4.12 which I need to change before running my tests.  Is there any way of configuring this from my travis file?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way of using the latest version of mongo which had features I was using in my tests.  See this [travis file](https://github.com/simon-p-r/json-schema-models/blob/master/.travis.yml) to show how I configured mongo to run my tests.